# How do I bind a MVC 5 list to a JSON object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, knockout.js

I have a list on my model

```
public SelectList listItems { get; set; }
```

I then select the items using linq to sql

```
var TypeDDL = TypeMethod();

private Type[] TypeMethod()
        {
            var TypeDDL = (from c in db.TypeLists select new Type { Type = c.Type, cid = c.ID }).ToArray();
            return TypeDDL;
        }
```

I then set this to a viewbag item

```
ViewBag.TypeDDL = new List<Type>(TypeDDL);
return View(m);
```

What I need to know is now how do I bind this to a Json object so that i can set it to a dropdownlist using knockoutjs

thanks mike

Comment: You can use JsonResult

Answer (score 1, accepted):

best way to do this is by using the html.raw helper and asigning your viewbag item to a object

```
var TypeList = Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewBag.TypeDDL));
```

and then in JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        var vm = new ViewModel();            
        vm.Type = ko.mapping.fromJS(@TypeList);
        ko.applyBindings(vm);
    });
</script>
```

please be aware iv used jQuery dom ready on this example

your then going to want to use a `@html.DropDownList` in your razor view:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Typelist", (SelectList)Model.listItems, new { 
    id = "id", 
    data_bind = " options: Type, optionsText: 'Type', optionsValue: 'id'" 
})
```

this will bind the list with knockout.js

Thanks

Comment: This seems to have been the best method, thanks Alan, but I cant up-vote you sorry

Comment: Plus this is using knockout which is perfect :)

Comment: As soon as i can ill up-vote your answer as well, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to involve a view in order to achieve this.

Rather, create a method on your controller that returns a JSON result

```
public ActionResult YourEndpointName()
{
    var list = TypeMethod();

    return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

This should create a json response which you can use to populate your ko viewmodel

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is I serialize the object in my controller first.

```
ViewBag.clubTypeDDL = JsonConvert.Serialize(new List<Type>(TypeDDL));
```

Then put it in a hidden input field on the view:

```
<input id="TypeDDL" value="@ViewBag.clubTypeDDL "/>
```

Then with a script:

```
<script>
    var json = $("#TypeDDL").val(); /// here is your json string
    // use this wherever you need
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to serialize `ViewBag.clubTypeDDL` to JSON:

```
<script>
var ClubTypes = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.clubTypeDDL));
</script>
```

Then bind your drop-down element's `options` to it:

```
<select data-bind="options: ClubTypes"></select>
```